# Is any traffic overload using double ng-repeat or ng-repeat with ng-if,ng-show,ng-switch? (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angularjs to make my project.

To show multi-depth-json data in browser, i had to use double `ng-repeat`

And some lists need exception handling, so i have used `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-switch`. (conditional expression are return value of function or just scope variable)

When you use this, ng-repeat causes traffic overload.

Specifically, one loop is looped twice, or it goes into an endless loop. (The result of the console command in the condition statement continues to appear.)

Anyone experienced similar experiences with me?

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in loopDatas" ng-show="conditional === true">
  <div>
      <div>{{value.valueName}}</div>        
  </div>    
  <div class="row" ng-switch="exceptionHandling(key)">
      <div ng-switch-when="A">
          <div ng-bind-html="getUIType(value)"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="B">
          <div ng-bind-html="getUIType(value)"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="C">
          <div ng-bind-html="getUIType(value)"></div>
      </div>        
      <div ng-switch-default ng-repeat='data in value.values'>
          <div ng-show='data.isInclude==true && visibleUIType(data) !== -1'>              
              <div bind-html-compile="getUIType(data)" ng-class="getCols(data)"></div>
          </div>
   </div>        
</div>
```

If you have solution or my code is wrong, please give solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are thinking about this the wrong way. It would be much more convenient and manageable to create a new array utilizing all of this logic in the controller. Then have a simple ng-repeat of the new array in the html.